# SQL variable/commands?

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

I am looking for a way to write the code below in a much shorter format. The "SET x..." part is what I want a quick command (Variable) to replace that part in the code below.

Also if there is a possibility to write the entire code with even more variables/commands for the different time spans instead of writing it out every time.

SET x = DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue)

```
SELECT
convert(varchar,TimeTrue,23) as Date,
TimeTrue as TimeTrueUTC,
DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue) as TimeTrue,
(CASE WHEN cast(TimeTrue as Date) BETWEEN '2021-02-08 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-11 00:00:00' THEN (CASE WHEN cast(DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue) as time(0)) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '14:59:59' THEN 0 WHEN cast(DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue) as time(0)) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '00:54:59' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
WHEN cast(TimeTrue as Date) BETWEEN '2021-07-12 00:00:00' AND '2021-08-29 00:00:00' THEN (CASE WHEN cast(DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue) as time(0)) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '14:29:59' THEN 0 WHEN cast(DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue) as time(0)) BETWEEN '14:30:00' AND '00:54:59' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
ELSE (CASE WHEN cast(DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue) as time(0)) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '13:59:59' THEN 0 WHEN cast(DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue) as time(0)) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '23:57:59' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) END) AS ShiftNo


FROM PerformanceOpcArchive (NOLOCK)
WHERE convert(varchar,TimeTrue,23)>='2021-03-24'
AND convert(varchar,TimeTrue,23)<='2021-03-29'
ORDER BY TimeTrue ASC
;
```

**What I'm looking for to write.**

```
SET @x = DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue)


SELECT
convert(varchar,TimeTrue,23) as Date,
TimeTrue as TimeTrueUTC,
@x as TimeTrue,
(CASE WHEN cast(TimeTrue as Date) BETWEEN '2021-02-08 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-11 00:00:00' THEN (CASE WHEN cast(@x as time(0)) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '14:59:59' THEN 0 WHEN cast(@x as time(0)) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '00:54:59' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
WHEN cast(TimeTrue as Date) BETWEEN '2021-07-12 00:00:00' AND '2021-08-29 00:00:00' THEN (CASE WHEN cast(@x as time(0)) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '14:29:59' THEN 0 WHEN cast(@x as time(0)) BETWEEN '14:30:00' AND '00:54:59' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
ELSE (CASE WHEN cast(@x as time(0)) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '13:59:59' THEN 0 WHEN cast(@x as time(0)) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '23:57:59' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) END) AS ShiftNo


FROM PerformanceOpcArchive (NOLOCK)
WHERE convert(varchar,TimeTrue,23)>='2021-03-24'
AND convert(varchar,TimeTrue,23)<='2021-03-29'
ORDER BY TimeTrue ASC
;
```

Comment: Are you looking for [APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) operator?

Comment: You can write a function and then call that function to do all the code.  It will add a step to the processing to call the function and then do all that you want.

UPDATE:  If you can use this type of thing in the powerbi realm (noticed that after I posted).

Comment: I believe I can use it. I can write SQL querys in Power BI. When looking into the function help on microsoft I dont understand how it fits in and how to write it tho.

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of datapart(tz) to get the offset in minutes from Central European Standard.(here see variable_x2)

Eg:

```
 select DATEADD(HOUR
                ,CAST(LEFT
                         (RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), SYSUTCDATETIME(), 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),SYSUTCDATETIME()
                ) as variable_x
      ,dateadd(minute
               ,datepart(tz,SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time') 
               ,SYSUTCDATETIME()) as variable_x2


+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|         variable_x          |         variable_x2         |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-09-13 13:59:42.8387246 | 2021-09-13 13:59:42.8387246 |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Not what I am looking for I believe. I want to call for variable_x instead of the entire code that is written.

I don't know what the function is called in SQL but I have looked into the DECLARE-funciton and can't seem to get that to work.

DECLARE @x =  DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(datetime2(0), TimeTrue, 126) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',4),1) as INT),TimeTrue)

Probably butchering the code and how to use the functions but not familiar with any of this and trying to find a way to make all that code into a simple statement as "@x" in example.

Comment: you would use dynamic sql to construct your query string first and set the variable @x. After that you would use EXEC (@qry_string) to execute the query. However this works in T-SQL as block of code with declare @x set@x=<code_for_timezone>' set @qry_string=concat('select ',@x,' from table') exec (@qry_string)